# Open specific page in twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

**How can I open a specific page in twitter bootstrap modal?**

I have this page

> NewUser.aspx

which contains a div and inherits the masterpage navigation menu.

I want to just open the div that contains the text boxes and buttons in the modal.

I've tried this

```
 <a data-target="#"  class="quick-btn" data-toggle="modal" href="/SystemSettings/NewUser.aspx" ></a>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $(url).modal('open');
            } else {
                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
                }).success(function() { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @ahmadtolpa - Edit your question to include this code instead of posting it in comments, then delete your comments once the question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

Markup:

Create a placeholder `DIV` to show the modal content within, like this:

```
<a data-target="#myModal" class="quick-btn" data-toggle="modal" href="/SystemSettings/NewUser.aspx">Click Me</a>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

Add the `.aspx` page's content to an `iframe`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>')
    });
});
```

Comment: the div is a good way ,its dim the page like it will open something .
But where i supposed to put my page url insdie the iframe ?

Comment: @ahmadtolpa - the page `URL` is pulled from the `href` of the anchor tag.

Comment: thanks a lot Karl for your help , but it didn't work .
its just dim the page and nothing happened

Comment: Is `/SystemSettings/NewUser.aspx` the correct path relative to where the JavaScript is running?

Comment: all of my code html and java script in 
/SystemSettings/SystemUsers.aspx
and the page i want to open is 
/SystemSettings/NewUser.aspx

Comment: @KarlAnderson in the Markup you have missed <div class="modal-body"></div> inside the 'myModal' div. Hence the $(".modal-body").html is not working.